# Sending graceful shutdown via AMT to intel NUC

Tags: intel, shutdown, amt, reboot

I have several intel NUC (NUC5i5MYBE) hosts with AMT support and an up-to-date firmware (2017-05-06).

I am able to send power-up and (hard) power-off and get the correct power info using [amtc](https://github.com/schnoddelbotz/amtc) and [Python AMT Tools](https://github.com/sdague/amt)

According to the [AMT 9.x notes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-active-management-technology-start-here-guide-intel-amt-9) there should be a way to send graceful shutdown (12) and graceful reboot (14). The version reported by the web interface (on port 16992) is `Intel® Active Management Technology firmware version: 10.0.55-build 3000`, so I should have this.

But when I send those commands, although I get an indication that the command was send successfully nothing was actually done by the NUC.

The OS that was suppose to perform the orderly shutdown is Windows 7.

Instead I get back an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<a:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:b="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:c="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd" xmlns:d="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:e="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:f="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/cimbinding.xsd" xmlns:g="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <a:Header>
    <b:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</b:To>
    <b:RelatesTo>uuid:05202c7a-dd61-4a1a-96e3-246359a58410</b:RelatesTo>
    <b:Action a:mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService/RequestPowerStateChangeResponse</b:Action>
    <b:MessageID>uuid:00000000-8086-8086-8086-000000000216</b:MessageID>
    <c:ResourceURI>http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService</c:ResourceURI>
  </a:Header>
  <a:Body>
    <g:RequestPowerStateChange_OUTPUT>
      <g:ReturnValue>2</g:ReturnValue>
    </g:RequestPowerStateChange_OUTPUT>
  </a:Body>
</a:Envelope>
```

I did not try to use [openwsman](https://openwsman.github.io/), because I wasn't able to figure out what are the proper arguments I need to use.

I also didn't find anything that I need to turn on or off in the NUC's BIOS settings nor in Windows.

So my question is: **Is graceful power-on and/or graceful reset are available at all via AMT on intel NUC 5i5MYBE? And if so how can I send those commands (preferably with some Linux command line tool or API, such as wsman)**

Answer (score 3):

Intel made this super complicated.

While a reasonable person could think that you can maybe do something half simple, like this:
`wsman invoke -a RequestPowerStateChange http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService -h ${AMT_HOST} -P 16992 -u admin -p ${AMT_PASSWORD} -k PowerState=10`

It’s much more “simple” than this. Judge for yourself:
`wsman invoke -a RequestPowerStateChange http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService -h ${AMT_HOST} -P 16992 -u admin -p ${AMT_PASSWORD}  -J /tmp/power.xml`

`cat /tmp/power.xml
<p:RequestPowerStateChange_INPUT xmlns:p="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_PowerManagementService">
  <p:PowerState>10</p:PowerState>
  <p:ManagedElement xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
            xmlns:wsman="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd">
    <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
      <wsman:ResourceURI>http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_ComputerSystem</wsman:ResourceURI>
      <wsman:SelectorSet>
        <wsman:Selector Name="CreationClassName">CIM_ComputerSystem</wsman:Selector>
        <wsman:Selector Name="Name">ManagedSystem</wsman:Selector>
      </wsman:SelectorSet>
    </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
  </p:ManagedElement>
</p:RequestPowerStateChange_INPUT>`